# load options in select jquery using grep

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following JSON String

```
var dropDownJSONval = '[
    { "Text": "Apple", "Value": "1" }, 
    { "Text": "Orange", "Value": "2" }, 
    { "Text": "pine", "Value": "3" }, 
    { "Text": "Grape", "Value": "4" }
]';
```

I need to add these JSON objects as a option in dropdown.

But,I dont need to add Grape in dropdown.How to ignore grape using GREP functionality in Jquery?

body

```
<div>
     <select id="fruits"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: - What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per OP comment on @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Answer

*i want to know that exact meaning of GREP*

Modified @RajaprabhuAravindasamy answer to use [**jQuery.grep()**](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/)

> Finds the elements of an array which satisfy a filter function. The original array is not affected.

Use

```
var fruits = $('#fruits');
 var dropDownJSONval = [{ "Text": "Apple", "Value": "1" }, { "Text": "Orange", "Value": "2" },{ "Text": "pine", "Value": "3" }, { "Text": "Grape", "Value": "4" }]; 

var filtered = jQuery.grep(dropDownJSONval, function(val){
    return val.Text !== "Grape"; 
})

$.each(filtered ,function(_,val){      
     fruits.append('<option value='+ val.Value +'>' + val.Text + '</option>');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hkR85/)

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
var fruits = $('#fruits');

$.each(dropDownJSONval ,function(_,val){ 
     if(val.Text==="Grape") { return; }
     fruits.append('<option value='+ val.Value +'>' + val.Text + '</option>');
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/54wfm/)

Comment: @Rajprabhu I need to load using GREP Functionality

Comment: @User why do you need grep especially..?

Comment: @ i want to know that exact meaning of GREP

Comment: @User, https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/

Comment: @User grep is actually used to manipulate/filter arrays. but you need append the elements in order to see the changes in the dom..